# Защитить get-параметры от подделки

Tags: php

На партнерском сайте пользователь заполняет и отправляет форму с параметрами order, email и amount на сайт оплаты заказа (в order хранится номер заказа).

После успешной или неудачной транзакции сайт оплаты перенаправляет пользователя по ссылке вида: [домен]/result?order=[номер заказа]&status=[success|refusal]. На основании этой ссылки на партнерском сайте заказ отмечается оплаченным или отмененным.

Что в этой логике я делаю не так? Есть ощущение что безопасность тут хромает, так как если пользователь знает номер заказа, то он может вручную через GET запросы отметить заказ как "оплаченный". Как обычно такое делают?

Comment: Обычно делается запрос на сайт оплаты заказа и проверяется действительно ли оплачен заказ.

Answer (score -1):

Обычно, в таблицу с заказами, вносится также `токен` для этого заказа. Генерируется он с   нескольких пользовательских параметров. Если клиентская машина не меняется за период оплаты, то ничего не стоит сгенировать тот же `токен` еще раз.

Comment: И что потом с этим токеном делать?

Comment: Сопоставлять имеющиеся данные с теми что генерируется в очередной раз.

Comment: Ну вот это и надо писать в ответе. подробно, с примерами. Вы, я вижу, тут недавно, поэтому имейте, пожалуйста, в виду, что Stack Overflow - это не форум, где можно порхать по темам и оставлять малозначительные ремарки, а сайт, который в первую очередь предназначен для предоставления ответов для тех, кто перешел из поиска. То есть ответ должен быть полезным и и подробным

Comment: Если клиентская машина не меняется за период оплаты, то ничего не стоит сгенировать тот же токен еще раз. == "Сопоставлять". И да... у меня только недавно появилась возможность оставлять комментарии. В рамках американского комУнити(?) это вполне себе нормально

Comment: Вы не поняли. Заклинание "сгенерировать токен" не отвечает на вопрос "Как защитить get-параметры от подделки". Это может быть частью ответа, возможно, очевидной для вас, но совершенно неочевидной для автора вопроса и будущих читателей. Поэтому надо не только написать про токен но так же и объяснить, что с ним делать.